# NullPointerException in Android onClick

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(545):     at no.jarle.f02.myActivity.onClick(myActivity.java:38)


public void onClick( View v )
{
    tvTextView.setText(editText1.getText());   <--- line 38
}


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".myActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The TextView should display the text user typed in the EditText when the button is clicked.
Instead it obviously crashes and i can't seem to find the problem. 
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: try to debug it - is `tvTextView` null or `editText1` null?

Comment: they were out of scope.. feel stupid now. thnx Daniel :)

Comment: @jario can you mark the correct answer, or answer it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   if (editText1.getText().toString().trim() > 0)

    tvTextView.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are having empty editText1 when you click on the button. So before you do setting text, just make sure you have something in the editText1. For example

```
if (editText1.getText().length>0)
   tvTextView.setText(editText1.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your TextView and/or EditText are only instanced on onCreate Method and they don't have "life" on your onClick method.

Is your class something like this?

```
Class YourClass {

private EditText editText1;

private TextView tvTextView;

public void `onCreate`(Bundle arg) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main)

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tvTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    tvTextView.setText(editText1.getText());
}
```

?

if your TextView and EditText are not attribute, you cant manipulate them on onClick.

or you can get the instance of them on `onClick` method using findViewById before try to setText.